# Dragging and resizing UIImages or UIButtons

Tags: iphone, uibutton

How does one take a UIButton or UIImageView and make it editable at runtime?

I would like the user to be able to move small UIImageViews or UIButtons around the screen, resizing them, dragging them etc.

I would like to make the corners of the squares or rectangles able to handle user interaction so that they can resize using the corners.

Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way to do that is to inherit from UIImageView/UIButton and override methonds that handle touch events.